# Java Jar run as Daemon cant issue exec()

Tags: java, linux, jar, daemon, runtime.exec

I have a java socket server I wrote to allow me to keep a web clusters code base in sync. When I run the init.d script from a shell login like so

```
[root@web11 www]# /etc/init.d/servermngr start
```

Logout and all will work fine but if the server reboots or I run the init.d using services like so

```
[root@web11 www]# service servermngr start
```

Any of the exec() commands passed to the socket server will not get executed on the linux box. I am assuming it has to do with the JVM having no real shell.  If I login and run

```
[root@web11 www]# /etc/init.d/servermngr start
```

...and logout all runs nice all CVS commands are executed.

Another note when run as a service the socket server responds to status checks so it is running

Here is the init.d script

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 95 1
# description: Starts Daemon Using ServerManager.jar.
# 
# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions


start () {
    echo -n $"Starting ServerManager: "

    # start daemon
    cd /www/servermanager/
    daemon java -jar ServerManager.jar > /www/logs/ServerManager.log &
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/cups
    echo "";
    return $RETVAL
}

stop () {
    # stop daemon
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    kill `ps uax | grep -i "java -jar ServerManager.ja[r]" | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`
    RETVAL=$?
    echo "";
    return $RETVAL
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

case $1 in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    *)

    echo $"Usage: servermngr {start|stop}"
    exit 3
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

And the Java responsible for actually executing the code:

```
// Build cmd Array of Strings
            String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "cd /www;cvs up -d htdocs/;cvs up -d phpinclude/"};
            final Process process;
            try {
                process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

                BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        process.getInputStream()));

                // Since this is a CVS UP we return the Response to PHP
                if(input.matches(".*(cvs up).*")){
                    String line1;
                    out.println("cvsupdate-start");
                    System.out.println("CVS Update" + input);
                    while ((line1 = buf.readLine()) != null) {
                        out.println(line1);
                        System.out.println("CVS:" + line1);
                    }
                    out.println("cvsupdate-end");
                }

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("IOException on Run cmd " + CommandFactory.class.getName() + " " + ex);
                Logger.getLogger(CommandFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Thx for any help

Comment: I checked the logfile I have it writing to and it is receiving the commands. It just isn't executing them on the server

Comment: [root@web11 ~]# tail -f /www/logs/ServerManager.log
Server Started on ip 192.168.56.151
Server Started on port 4444
MaxConnections:0
CVS Update:cd /www;cvs up -d htdocs/;cvs up -d phpinclude/
CVS Update:cd /www;cvs up -d htdocs/;cvs up -d phpinclude/

So the commands make it to the `process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);`
@Ingo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the command you are trying to run? `cd` is not a program and if you have `;` you have multiple commands. You can only run one program!

Comment: The socket server gets commands sent to it and they are issued this way: 
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c","cd /www;cvs up -d htdocs/;cvs up -d phpinclude/"}
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: Thats fine. `sh` is a single command. What error message do you get if it fails? If you want to perform remote commands, did you consider `ssh` which designed for this?

Comment: The socket servers are operating properly now but that is because I logged into all 10 Servers and issued /etc/init.d/servermngr start then logged out.  If they server goes down or is rebooted the OS will launch service servermngr start (i also tried adding to rc.local) and after that the commands no longer get passed to the Server OS Linux.  I get no error from Linux or Java. Once I log into the server and do a service servermngr stop and a /etc/init.d/servermngr start it will work again but I need for it to work via service

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought as well. Yet I see nothing I edited and posted the code responsible for running the exec() command. I hard coded and example command "cd /www;cvs up -d htdocs/;cvs up -d phpinclude/" into it. Usually this is sent in the JSON string sent to each server

Comment: Your answer got me thinking so I added some code to the Java server and found that the CVSROOT enviroment variable was not set. I added export CVSROOT=":pserver:cvs@cvs.xyz.net:/cvsroot";  to the startup script and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Are you starting the process as root?  What version of (bash?) is running on the system?  You may want to give csh a whirl just to rule out issues with the shell itself.  I'd also suggest chaining the commands with '&' instead of ';'.  Finally you may find it easier to create a shell script which contains all your commands and is called by your java process.  You may also want to investigate nohup and check /etc/security/limits

Comment: bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: The only problem I see is I cant issue any commands to the OS. Im wondering if it is because the java program isnt running in a shell when started on reboot or via service. I will try the & between cmds

Comment: and yes it is running as root

Answer (score 0):

You might be happier using http://akuma.kohsuke.org/ to help you with this stuff, or at least Apache Commons Exec.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the startup script that fixed my issue if someone runs into an issue

```
#!/bin/sh
# chkconfig: 2345 95 1
# description: Starts Daemon Using ServerManager.jar.
# 
# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

RETVAL=0
prog="ServerManager"
servermanager="java"
serveroptions=" -jar ServerManager.jar"
pid_file="/var/run/servermanager.pid"

launch_daemon()
{
  /bin/sh << EOF
     java -Ddaemon.pidfile=$pid_file $serveroptions <&- &
     pid=\$!
     echo \${pid}
EOF
}

start () {
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
 if [ -e /var/lock/subsys/servermanager ]; then
                if [ -e /var/run/servermanager.pid ] && [ -e /proc/`cat /var/run/servermanager.pid` ]; then
                echo -n $"cannot start: servermanager is already running.";
                failure $"cannot start: servermanager already running.";
                echo
                return 1
                fi
        fi
    # start daemon
    cd /www/voodoo_servermanager/
    export CVSROOT=":pserver:cvsd@cvs.zzzzz.yyy:/cvsroot";
    daemon "$servermanager $serveroptions > /www/logs/ServerManager.log &"
    #daemon_pid=`launch_daemon`
    #daemon ${daemon_pid}
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    [ $RETVAL = 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/servermanager && pidof $servermanager > $pid_file
    echo "";
    return $RETVAL
}

stop () {
    # stop daemon
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
        if [ ! -e /var/lock/subsys/servermanager ]; then
            echo -n $"cannot stop ServerManager:  ServerManager is not running."
            failure $"cannot stop ServerManager:  ServerManager is not running."
        echo
        return 1;
        fi
        killproc $servermanager
        RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/servermanager;
        return $RETVAL
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

case $1 in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    restart)
        restart
    *)

    echo $"Usage: servermngr {start|stop|restart}"
    RETVAL=1
esac

exit $RETVAL
```